# Modify partially-functional code to delete cell contents based in the time input of a certain cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've got a current project which takes the time of a cell (in this case, C5), and if the current time is greater than the time input in cell C5, it deletes a range of cells. I'm using this as a rudimentary "auto clock-out" system that removes someone after their finish time, which is input in C5, has elapsed.

Here is the current code:

```
function CO1() {

  var s =    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
             .getSheetByName('Timestamps');
  var curTime = new Date()
  var expTime = s.getRange("C5").getDisplayValue().split(":")
  Logger.log(curTime.getHours() +":"+curTime.getMinutes())
  Logger.log(expTime[0]+":"+expTime[1])

  if (curTime.getHours() >= expTime[0] && curTime.getMinutes() >= expTime[1]){
    Logger.log("Clear")
    s.getRange('C3').clearContent(),s.getRange('C4').clearContent(),s.getRange('C5').clearContent(),s.getRange('E6').clearContent(),s.getRange('E7').clearContent();
  }
}
```

This worked while operating between normal hours (09:00 - 17:00), but now, during quarantine, we're operating strange hours. Some of the finish times now end up into the early hours (such as 20:00 - 04:00). At midnight, it treats the time as being expired, and deletes all of the cell data.

Is there any way to mitigate this from happening, please?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is stored in C5, could you please add some example data?

Comment: The example is essentially a tool for clocking out at the end of a "shift", so the value in C5 is the finish time. For example, a person was finishing their shift at 15:45. They would put 15:45 in the cell C5. The script checks the current time against the time in C5, and once the current time has exceeded the time in cell C5, the data is automatically removed.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (curTime.getHours() >= 9 && curTime.getHours()<17){
```